# START_STICKY doesn't restart service after the app crush

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-anr-dialog

I got a service that stops for a reason I'm still not sure why with ANR massage.
The service is starting in the `onStartCommand()`
 with a Thread and returning `START_STICKY` flag.

The service is using the Bluetooth feature with another 2 separate Threads that runs in a never ending loop for scanning devices (with `ThreadSleep` for saving battery and CPU mostly).

**Edit:** I used the Bluetooth feature and when I closed it, the service that was scanning for devices couldn't get the `BluetoothAdapter` and the app collapsed, it wasn't ANR message.

any way I still need a way to handle this situation. I need to make sure that when the service crush it will try to reset by himself some way. I've considerd using `BroadcastReceiver` for the Bluetooth state.

---

1. *Can you help me understand why I get this ANR message and how to
   solve it? ask for more specific info.* **Edit: Not relevant any more.**
2. Do I make a mistake to run a never ending loop in a thread in
   service and expect it to keep on running?
3. After the service shutdown, I saw once the service came back to
   life, but now it doesn't. What way should I use to make sure the
   service will restart in the nearest time after crushing or shutting down?

---

Any tips and info connected to this confusing topic will help a lot!

Comment: Post your colde maybe, and the error message also.

Comment: I realized why the service crushed or at least one of the reasons for it. I'm not sure if there are more. I edited the question and I still need a bit help with my other two questions if you can help.